# How To (set) Make Jquery Variable as Background Image

Tags: jquery

I need to help How To (set) Make Jquery Variable as (div) Background Image, here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".my-div-1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src');
    var images = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#my-div').css('backgroundImage', 'url(i-need-to-change-this-value-with-src)');
  });

});
```

```css
#my-div {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/800')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img_pilihan">
  <div id="my-div">#my-div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question!

Comment: You're selecting an ID in your script that doesn't exist in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

I found solutuion

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $( ".img_pilihan" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).attr('src');
        var images = $( this ).attr('src');
        $('#bahan').css('background-image', 'url(' + images + ')');
        
});
        
    
});
```